# I want player to display their real body on the game (in front of background) instead of cartoon model

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I am creating kinect project by Use C# in visual 2013. My project scope is about exercise shoulder in term of game and I use Unity program for create scene and GUI. In my project, Player have to move their shoulder then kinect will detect. I want player to display their real body on the game (in front of background) instead of cartoon model. What should I do??? 
Can anyone help me. please 
Thank you.

Comment: I don't have expert knowledge on kinect-sdk so this is more like an idea than an answer. Have you tried using the camera to capture the player and then replay it on your scene? If it's possible with kinect-sdk of course.

Comment: but I want to show only their body not include background after their body. Thank you for your comment

Comment: I see. Well unfortunately this is beyond my limited knowledge. Hope you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Kinect SDK contains a sample named "Coordinate Mapping Basics-WPF" which demonstrates removing the background and leaving the people from color frames. That should be good starting point for your project.